# existing django module name clashes with new pip package

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, pypi

I already had a module inside my django project called (let's say) `abcxyz`. Now after several months into the project, i came across a new pip package which might be useful for some new features that we are thinking of. Unfortunately, it's registered in PyPI as `abcxyz` also - conincidence, huh?

After installing this new found package via `pip install abcxyz`, now when i try to import the package by using `import abcxyz` it ends up importing the existing `abcxyz` module (which i already had in my django project for months) and not the new package that i just installed.

How do i resolve this issue?

Is there any way i could install the PyPI package under a different name in my project since i already have that name being used for an existing module?

Or,

Is there any way to explicitly specify that i want to import abcxyz (the pip package) and not abcxyz (the django module) in my `import` statement?

Comment: If you have multiple modules with the same name, `import abcxyz` will import whichever module comes first in the `sys.path`. There is no way to rename an installed package (well, actually it's possible to rename the files on FS and adjust package metadata, but you don't want to do that for sure). You can switch to local imports of your own module with `from . import abcxyz` and import the installed package with global import, but the best way is to rename your own module to avoid name shadowing issues once and for all.

Comment: Btw you don't need to rename the module, just create another package and move the module inside it, so your imports change from `import abcxyz` to `import myproj.abcxyz` or `from myproj import abcxyz`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

then you'll need to import your local package with

```
from . import abcxyz
```

and the pip-installed package with

```
import abcxyz
```